# How to count based origin of the data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this data:

```
userid   a.birthday   b.birthday   c.birthday
12        2017-01-01    2017-01-01   NULL
13        2016-01-12    2016-01-12   2016-01-12
14          NULL        2017-04-05   NULL
```

I have the following query:

```
select COALESCE(a.birthday,b.birthday,c.birthday) as birthday
from ....
```

This gives me the birthday date based on the source first I take it from `a` if exists else from `b` else from `c` .... The outpuut of the query is:

```
birthday
-------
2017-01-01   #from a.birthday
2016-01-12   #from a.birthday
2017-04-05   #from b.birthday
count(3)
```

---

What I want to do know is to know what is the source of the birthday date that was chosen for this query.

So what I actually want to see is:

```
    a b c
   -------
    2 1 0
```

Note that It can't be done with simple counting the tables.

While `userid=12` has birthday listed in both `a` and `b` in my query I take it from a so when counting I want to count it as `a` and not in `b`.

How can I do such counting of records in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a simple case expression:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.birthday IS NOT NULL THEN 'a'
            WHEN b.birthday IS NOT NULL THEN 'b'
            WHEN c.birthday IS NOT NULL THEN 'c' END AS src
```

This will give you the *preferred* source. You can group by this expression when counting (it'll give you three rows instead of three columns).

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    -- a is not null 
    count(a.birthdate) as a
    -- a is null
    ,count(case when a.birthdate is null then b.birthdate end) as b
    -- a and b are both null
    ,count(case when coalesce(a.birthdate,b.birthdate) is null then c.birthdate end) as c
from tab
```